# How to get <video> tag in HTML to work with Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video-streaming

I have some video clips on my web site at [richard-parkins.free.nf](https://richard-parkins.free.nf). Currently they load and display with bino in a separate window, but vlc can't play them, which I have reported separately in the vlc forum. I would like to stream them so that the user does not have to wait for the whole video clip to download. I have searched on the Internet and found instructions to do something like this:-

```html
  <video id="player" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" controls>
   <source src="http://richard-parkins.free.nf/bc.mp4"
     type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

but if I run this code in Firefox 115.7.0esr (64-bit), it says

No video with supported format and MIME type found

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

says

```
NAME="openSUSE Leap"
VERSION="15.5"
ID="opensuse-leap"
ID_LIKE="suse opensuse"
VERSION_ID="15.5"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Leap 15.5"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:leap:15.5"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Leap"
LOGO="distributor-logo-Leap"
```

Hardware is a Dell Precision 7700 with an external 4K monitor.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no file located at `http://richard-parkins.free.nf/bc.mp4`? It can work, see: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/mdoGrVO

Comment: I'm using Firefox 115.8.0esr (64-bit), I get "Video can't be played because the file is corrupt" trying to play a .mp4 file directly, and "Settings" doesn't seem to be able to specify a program to play this file. The example code given by KIKO Software gives "No video with supported format and MIME type found". I replaced the .mp4 with a .avi file. This will play using bino if I load it directly into a Firefox window, but the HTML code to stream it doesn't work: it gets into an endless  wait loop.

Comment: There still doesn't seem to be a file at `http://richard-parkins.free.nf/bc.mp4`. I get a [302 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=devtools-netmonitor&utm_campaign=default). I noticed you seem to use [Free Website Hosting](https://www.infinityfree.com), they [don't allow hosting of videos](https://forum.infinityfree.com/t/error-playing-video/7834) for obvious reasons. If you want to serve larger quantities of data you have to pay for it yourself. I could have told you this 3 weeks ago....

Comment: No, there isn't an mp4, because it didn't work. The avi is there, and I can download it and play it. However my understanding was they do allow streaming, which is the reason why I was trying to do it.